unity - how to make rigidbody don't move above another one
My scene consists on the dog pushing table away from sleeping guy to stole their donut.

So I made Rigidbodies for Table, Plate and Donut objects.



The problem is that when the player pushes the table, the plate above its moving too fast to table border. I need it to stays above the table.
I tried to freeze its position and set Kinematic, but no success.
Is it a configuration problem? Or do I need to code it in another way?

make the plate a child to the table?

Can you make a gif of the moment when you're pushing the table and edit the post to show it? This could be useful to see better the issue :)

Try freezing the rigidbody's x and z properties by clicking the checkboxes pictured in the screenshot.

